# Protected routes in next js

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js

I have two types of user . when user login i need to redirect them based on their role . Also protect routes. Only login user can go to specific routes based on their role. how this can be done in next js

Answer (score 0):

You can get the auth token and create a `serverSideProps` https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props to redirect the user by role.

Answer (score 0):

when the user logs into your app, you can save his permission in cookies and then get his permission via [serverSideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props), and render the page according to the user.